# Java hashmap to matrix conversion

Tags: java, matrix, hashmap, sparse-matrix

I initiated a hashmap and a nested hashmap to store term, its occurrences, and frequency.

```
for (i = 1; i < lineTokens.length; i += 2) 
{   
    if (i + 1 >= lineTokens.length) continue;  
    String fileName = lineTokens[i];
    int frequency = Integer.parseInt(lineTokens[i + 1]); 
    postingList2.put(fileName,frequency);
    //System.out.println(postingList2);
}
postingList.put(topic, postingList2);
```

It gives me output: {cancel={WET4793.txt=16, WET5590.txt=53}, unavailable={WET4291.txt=10}, station info={WET2266.txt=32}, advocacy program={WET2776.txt=32}, no ratingslogin={WET5376.txt=76}, 
I am trying to represent the whole things in a matrix. But I cannot set 0 to the files who don't contain the specific term. 
It's like:

```
row-> term
column -> document
mat[row][column]= frequency of occurances of terms in the document.
```

I have easily done it in python using pandas dataframe.

Comment: So, where is your code for map to matrix conversion? Have you tried to use `List` for your matrix?

Comment: yeah, I tried to use List for my matrix using two loops. But I cannot come out with the solution. 

    for (int termIndex=0; termIndex< postingList.size();termIndex++)
    {
        for (int fileNameIndex=0; 
        fileNameIndex<postingList.get(topicArray[0]).size(); fileNameIndex++)
        {
                    
        }
   }

I am trying my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your initial HashMap, to convert to a Matrix requires three steps

1. Create a unique index id for each topic (0, 1 ..)
2. Create a unique index id for each document (0, 1, ..)
3. Populate the matrix using the above indices

This solution will use a Map lookup (keys are posting/document) for efficiency.  The order of the postings/documents can be controlled; here there is no attempt to create a *specific* order.

**Step 1**: Create unique id for postings and create lookup Map

```
Map<String, Integer> topicIndex = new HashMap<>();
List<String> topicList = new ArrayList<>();  // topicList is used to print the matrix
int index = 0;
for (String topic : postingList.keySet()) {
    if (!topicIndex.containsKey(topic)) {
        topicIndex.put(topic, index++);
        topicList.add(topic);
    }
}
```

The results of this map are (all terms now have a unique id):

```
Topics: {cancel=0, unavailable=1, station info=2, advocacy program=3, no ratingslogin=4}
```

**Step 2:**  Create unique id for documents and create lookup Map

```
index = 0;
Map<String, Integer> documentIndex = new HashMap<>();
for (String topic : postingList.keySet()) {
    for (String document : postingList.get(topic).keySet()) {
        if (!documentIndex.containsKey(document))
            documentIndex.put(document, index++);
    }
}
```

The results of this Map are (all documents now have a unique id):

```
Documents: {WET4793.txt=0, WET4291.txt=2, WET2266.txt=3, WET2776.txt=4, WET5376.txt=5, WET5590.txt=1}
```

**Step 3:** Create and populate the matrix

```
int[][] mat = new int[topicIndex.size()][documentIndex.size()];
for (String topic : postingList.keySet()) {
    for (String document : postingList.get(topic).keySet()) {
        mat[topicIndex.get(topic)][documentIndex.get(document)] = postingList.get(topic).get(document);
    }
}
```

**Results:** The matrix now looks like this:

```
cancel          16 53  0  0  0  0 
unavailable      0  0 10  0  0  0 
station info     0  0  0 32  0  0 
advocacy program 0  0  0  0 32  0 
no ratingslogin  0  0  0  0  0 76
```

EDIT:  Loop to print the matrix

```
    for (int row = 0; row < topicIndex.size(); row++) {
        System.out.printf("%-16s", topicList.get(row));
        for (int col = 0; col < documentIndex.size(); col++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", mat[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But how your matrix looks like this? I tried with two for loop to print the result matrix. but it is not showing output like you.

Comment: You are welcome.  The answer has been edited to show the logic I used to print the matrix

Comment: Hello Ian, it worked. I messed up on something silly. Then I fixed it. It totally works. Thanks man.